# Subtracting two columns from two different table with different data

Tags: sql-server

i had this problem where i got two tables with different values.

TABLE 1:

```
Description    Qty   Amount
Proc 1          1     100
Proc 2          1      50
Proc 3          1      60
```

TABLE 2:

```
Description     Payment
  Proc 1          60
  Proc 1          30
  Proc 2          20
  Proc 3          60
  Proc 2          20
```

So, the result should be like:

```
Description     Balance
  Proc 1          10
  Proc 2          40
  Proc 3           0
```

How will i do this with select query? thanks.

I Already tried this code but it should first get the distinct rows of TABLE1 and sum distinct values from TABLE2 before subtracting the two tables.

```
SELECT FEESList.[Fee Description], sum(StudentBILLING.Quantity* StudentBILLING.Total- isnull(StudReceipts.Amount,0)) as Balance
FROM StudentBILLING INNER JOIN FEESList ON StudentBILLING.FeeID = FEESList.FeeID INNER JOIN SREGStudentInformation ON StudentBILLING.StudentID = SREGStudentInformation.ID INNER JOIN
      SemesterList ON StudentBILLING.SemesterID = SemesterList.SemID INNER JOIN SchoolYear ON StudentBILLING.SYid = SchoolYear.[SY ID] FULL JOIN StudReceipts ON FEESList.FeeID = StudReceipts.FeeID
WHERE (SREGStudentInformation.[Student ID] = @StudentNumber) AND (SemesterList.[Sem.] = @Sem) AND (SchoolYear.[School Year] = @SchoolYear) AND 
      (FEESList.[Type of Fee] = 2) AND (StudentBILLING.Quantity* StudentBILLING.Total- ISNULL(StudReceipts.Amount,0))>0
GROUP BY FEESList.[Fee Description]
```

The result is from this;

```
Description    Amount   Payments
    Proc 1      100       60
    Proc 1      100       30
    Proc 2      50        20
    Proc 2      50        20
    Proc 3      60        60
```

To this result which is not supposed to be.

```
Description    Amount   
    Proc 1      100     
    Proc 2      50
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: It sort of looks like you want table1 - minus sum(table2) but your math is incorrect. Have you tried using SUM???

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try using a `join`? Other than that why is `Proc 2` resulting balance `40` when Table 2 has two `Proc 2`'s that have payments of 20 each? Shouldn't it be 10 since it would be 50 - 20 - 20?

Comment: @Simon I added some details to my post, can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try below with sample data which you have provided

First, it will generated row numbers by using `row_number()` function partition by `Description` and  `Payment` column which has duplicate payment made & `sum()` if have duplicate payments made

```
;WITH cte AS (
     SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Description],
                                           Payment ORDER BY [Description]) rn
     FROM <TABLE 2>)
     SELECT t.[Description],
            CASE
                WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT c.rn) > 1 THEN SUM(c.Payment)
                ELSE MAX(t.amount) - SUM(c.Payment)
            END [Balance]
     FROM cte c
          JOIN <TABLE 1> t ON t.[Description] = c.[Description]
     GROUP BY t.[Description];
```

Result :

```
Description     Balance
  Proc 1          10
  Proc 2          40
  Proc 3           0
```

**Note**, But you could also check with your sample data what if one Description has both Payments made one is duplicate and other is unique ??

Answer (score 0):

You're maths isn't correct
Proc 2 = Tabl1 50, Tab2 20+ 20 = balance = 10

```
DECLARE @tab1 TABLE ([Description] NVARCHAR(15), Qty INT, Amount INT )
INSERT INTO @tab1
([Description], Qty, Amount)
SELECT 'Proc 1',1,100 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Proc 2',1,50 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Proc 3',1,60

DECLARE @tab2 TABLE ([Description] NVARCHAR(15), Payment INT)
INSERT INTO @tab2
([Description], Payment)
SELECT 'Proc 1', 60 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Proc 1', 30 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Proc 2', 20 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Proc 3', 60 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Proc 2', 20


SELECT
      T.[Description]
    , Balance = (T.Qty * T.Amount) - X.Payment
FROM @tab1 T
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
          T.[Description]
        , Payment = SUM(T.Payment) 
    FROM @tab2 T    
    GROUP BY T.[Description]
) X ON X.[Description] = T.[Description]
```

Comment: Can you help me do it with the sample code i provided? I tried yours but it seems giving me some errors. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Left joining from a derived table will solve your issue. Alternatively you could have done it the slightly longer route by doing aggregation in a cte and then a join

```
select t1.description
       ,t1.amount - t2.sum as balance
from table1 t1
left join 
(select description
       ,sum(payment) as sum
from table2
group by description) t2 on t1.description = t2.description
```

Just some food for thought:

You want to use a `left join` instead of an `inner join`. `Left join` says if it's in this first table and not second, show null. `Inner join` says show it only if it is in BOTH tables. And I'm guessing you want to show the balance even if a payment hasn't been made (just a guess but that's up to your report).

Here's the [rextester](http://rextester.com/FNX72462) sample you can play with.